# M14 runnodes cannot start the Controller

Tags: corda

After upgrading to M14, the controller node cannot start with the following exception.
Is there anything different from M13 here?
Thanks.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/corda/webserver/services/WebServerPluginRegistry
```

\Sean

Comment: In your `build.gradle` file, what version do you have for `corda_gradle_plugins_version`?

Comment: Joel, it is 0.14.0

Answer (score 1):

This issue is generally caused by having a single plugin file implements WebServerPluginRegistry while also subclassing CordaPluginRegistry.

You can fix this by splitting the `WebServerPluginRegistry` and `CordaPluginRegistry` into two separate classes.

Comment: Thanks, Joel.  That does it.