# Corda: Error in starting node after upgrade to v1.0 and added Serialization whitelist to META-INF.services

Tags: corda

Error message when starting up a corda node.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
      net/corda/webserver/services/WebServerPluginRegistry
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(Unknown Source)
```

The codes for the plugin:

```
class testcasePlugin : SerializationWhitelist, WebServerPluginRegistry{

override val webApis = listOf(
        Function(::MiscApi),

)

override val staticServeDirs: Map<String, String> = mapOf(
        // URL is /web/index
        "index" to javaClass.classLoader.getResource("index").toExternalForm(),
        // URL is /web/testcase
        "testcase" to javaClass.classLoader.getResource("testcase").toExternalForm()
)

override val whitelist: List<Class<*>> = listOf(TransactionBuilder::class.java)
}
```

The trick to get ride of the error is to delete the 'net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationWhitelist' file from the META-INF.services folder leaving only the 'net.corda.webserver.services.WebServerPluginRegistry' file.

Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45855475/m14-runnodes-cannot-start-the-controller.

Comment: Right @joel but there is no more CordaPluginRegistry, so what is the correct way to do this white list serialisation?

Answer (score 0):

You have to split the plugin into two, as follows:

```
class testcaseWebPlugin : WebServerPluginRegistry {

override val webApis = listOf(
    Function(::MiscApi))

override val staticServeDirs: Map<String, String> = mapOf(
    // URL is /web/index
    "index" to javaClass.classLoader.getResource("index").toExternalForm(),
    // URL is /web/testcase
    "testcase" to javaClass.classLoader.getResource("testcase").toExternalForm()
)

class testcaseSerializationPlugin : SerializationWhitelist {

    override val whitelist: List<Class<*>> = 
        listOf(TransactionBuilder::class.java)
    }
}
```